# Coefficient of fraternity between grandparent and grandchild from full-sib parents

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, quantitative-genetics

I have the following pedigree and I would like to calculate the coefficient of fraternity between individual 1 and 5. R/AGHmatrix::Amatrix gives a coefficient of 0 for this pair. Shouldn't it be non-zero since there is still chance for individual 1 and 5 to have the same genotype? E.g. if the genotype in individual 1 is AB, there is still 1/8 chance to pass the alleles down to get AB in individual 5. Thanks.

| ID | Parent 1 | Parent 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: I think you're probably using the software wrong/there's a bug in your code.